# The atime of a NFS directory does not get updated

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, mount, nfs

I have been trying to `stat` a directory in my file share that got mounted from NFS Server  [which is VM Debian 8.11], After i've `touch`ed a file in the directory and read the directory content by `ls` ,the `atime,mtime and ctime` got modified ,So things went fine here,And then i did the same on my file share that mounted from physical machine [which is Debian 7.9], the `atime` of the directory remains the same though i have `touch`ed and `ls`ed the directory. both of these file share were mounted by `realtime`,I wonder why does it happen. when I just ran `mount` on the physical machine[NFS SERVER] ,I could see most of its local files are mounted with `noatime`

```
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=26352140k,mode=755)
/dev/sda2 on /lib/live/mount/medium type ext4 (rw,noatime,user_xattr,data=ordered)
/dev/loop0 on /lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
tmpfs on /lib/live/mount/overlay type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /lib/live/mount/overlay type tmpfs (rw,noatime,mode=755)
aufs on / type aufs (rw,noatime,si=b3e6ae3b999120a9,noxino)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=52704260k)
/dev/sda2 on /var/lib/dsnet-config type ext4 (rw,noatime,user_xattr,data=ordered)
/dev/sda2 on /var/log type ext4 (rw,noatime,user_xattr,data=ordered)
/dev/sda2 on /var/spool/rsyslog type ext4 (rw,noatime,user_xattr,data=ordered)
/dev/sda2 on /var/lib/dsnet-core type ext4 (rw,noatime,user_xattr,data=ordered)
/dev/sda2 on /var/lib/dsnet-md type ext4 (rw,noatime,user_xattr,data=ordered)
/dev/sda2 on /etc/corosync type ext4 (rw,noatime,user_xattr,data=ordered)
/dev/sda2 on /var/lib/heartbeat type ext4 (rw,noatime,user_xattr,data=ordered)
```

Ain't sure whether the above mounts has to deal with my problem , yet these are the only oddity I have been seeing between them.

And one more question to ask if I give a NFS request like `MKDIR()` will this call take the time info from client or it does take it from the NFS SERVER

Answer (score 1):

Modern Linux systems do not record directory access times unless the filesystem is mounted with the `diratime` option. This is because updating access time has a significant performance impact and directory access times, unlike access times of regular files, are not very useful because they are very frequently updated (as soon as someone runs `ls` in the directory, when updating the locate database, …).

If you want directory access times to be recorded, you need to mount the filesystem with the `diratime` option on the server. (In principle you should also pass `diratime` on the client but I think the NFS driver, unlike most other filesystems, ignores this option and lets the server update directory atimes implicitly.)

Comment: This could be a NFS cache coherency issue as well.

Comment: @Giles: I think that you may be mistaken, according to the mount manpage:  "diratime
              Update directory inode access times on this filesystem. This is the default."  Thus, directory access time is changed UNLESS disabled.

Comment: @mdpc That's the default for the mount command, but not for the kernel.